# Using probabilities from a model as features to another

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I'd like to use the probability output from a model as features to another model.

For instance, I want to determine what kind of bird is on a picture, I want to use a CNN, train it and then use the probability result with other data, like size and weight from the bird, and feed it to a svm.

Do I need to use training and testing set for extracting these probabilities using the CNN? Should I devide my dataset into folds and then extract the probabilities for each different testing fold or can I just train and test on all my data and save the probabilities?

Answer (score 1):

A test set is intended to validate your classifier reaches its goals, or alternatively to set hyper-parameters. In this case, you're not interested in the output of the CNN, as it's just an intermediate layer in the bigger picture.

Having said that, you're apparently not back-propagating SVM errors through its inputs. That's the consequence of a two-stage model. If you did, you'd be optimizing the CNN for use as input to that particular SVM.

Comment: So training and testing a single CNN is ok in this case? Isn't it overfiting?

Comment: @LucasRamos: Let's assume for a moment that the CNN does overfit. The problem is that the CNN outputs are optimal for the training data, but you have generalization errors on other data. Will you be training the SVM with the same data? If so, then the SVM will suffer from the generalization error on its inputs. If not, the SVM will negate those